# Any ideas why Google not caching my site?

Tags: google, cache

The site is www.books-for-children.com, developed in Wordpress CMS. It was launched about two months ago and still has  not been cached by Google, which seems highly unusual. Any ideas where I might look for answers?

Comment: We need some more information than that - have you submitted a valid sitemap to Google? Do you have an Analytics or Webmaster Tools account?

Answer (score 17):

Because you [*told* them](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/02/robots-exclusion-protocol.html) not to(see under "Controlling Caching and Snippets"):

```
<meta name="robots" content="noodp,noydir,noarchive,nosnippet"/>
```

...along with several other things not to do.

As to why that is, you'll have to inspect your WordPress installation(settings, SEO plugins) and theme files to figure out exactly where that tag's coming from, but it looks like the Yoast plugin is doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Additional from what Su' said, this is from the [Google FAQ](https://sites.google.com/site/webmasterhelpforum/en/faq--crawling--indexing---ranking/#not-indexed):

> **Q: My site isn't indexed yet!**
>
> **A:** Crawling and indexing are processes which can take some time and which rely on many factors. In general,
> we cannot make predictions or guarantees about when or if your URLs
> will be crawled or indexed. When looking at a site's indexing in
> Webmaster Tools, make sure that you have both the "www" and the
> "non-www" versions (like "www.example.com" and "example.com") verified
> and have a set a preferred domain. Keep in mind that while a Sitemap
> file can help us learn about your site, it does not guarantee indexing
> or increase your site's ranking.

Answer (score 2):

You Try to do this.

Open the Wordpress admin then go to Setting=> Privacy =>Allow search engines to index this site => Save..

It Caches Wordpress Sites.

Answer (score 0):

You can suggest your site in Googles Webmaster tools. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Which means, you need to generate a sitemap.xml within Wordpress. There are plugins that do that for you. Also check if you have blocked out search engines from within your admin dashboard. Check under "Settings" -> "Privacy" and make sure "Allow search engines to index this site." is checked.